# windows workflow foundation custom activity - Hide properties at runtime

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I have an workflow and on step 1 the user should see this:

[image]

Instead it see's this (the "Value" field is the one that should be only one visible):

[image]

The extra fields are the properties visible also on design:

[image]

Can i hide these properties on runtime?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "the user should see this"; how is the user seeing this?  What are you using to expose the dialog you show?

Comment: The user opens from the application menu, the order page and on the first step of the order workflow it should be quantity selector.The user will insert desired quantity and click next for the second step of the workflow.